# What does the Create Web App + Database option offer in portal azure

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I'm looking at creating a web app in portal azure but I came across this option. Create Web App + Database.

My question is if I select the DB engine to be SQL Azure. How big is the database?

Also, what's the difference between the Basic and Standard hosting plans?

[image: screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/azure/creating-web-app-tutorial-pricing#:~:text=Azure%20Web%20Apps%20provides%20an,js%2C%20and%20Python.) Answer for your question?

Comment: Thanks  Amareswarapu for the link. but my question was more about the database engine option etc

Answer (score 1):

> How big is the database?

The `SQLAzure` option refers to the Serverless Azure SQL Database offering. [Source](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/01/26/webapp-db-create.html)

Like most of Azure's managed SQL offerings, it scales up based on how much data you throw at it over time, but it appears the limit for storage is 2TB. [Source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-sql-database-storage-limits-increase-for-selected-compute-sizes-in-general-purpose-and-business-critical-tiers/)

> Also, what's the difference between the Basic and Standard hosting plans?

This is pretty explicitly addressed on the [App Service Pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/). Among other differences, the Standard plan comes with more disk space for your app and supports auto-scaling of the underlying resources.